# TCP IP Performance on the same machine

Tags: linux, tcp

When I run a TCP server and client on the same machine what I am observing is that the client send time (that is timestampT1 , send() , timestampT2 ; timestampT2  - timestampT1  ) is significantly higher in the tail percentiles than if I run the same server on a different machine.

With all TCP parameters, software and machine specs being equal if client takes 10 mirco sec in the mean and 20-25 mircoseconds in the 90-99th percentile for 1 million sends in case of server and client on different boxes , it takes 10 microsec in the mean and 70-100 microseconds in the 90-99th percentile for server and client on same box.

I have tried playing with interuupt isolation, socket send buffer sizing and CPU pinning with no significant improvements. This is RHEL 5.6.

Any possible explanation for this ?

Comment: is the traffic going out and then coming back? are u doing it based on ip and some name?

Comment: hmm.. are you trying to do two sends() in quick succession? or you just measure one send()?

Comment: @yi_H I am doing one send every 200 mircoseconds and there are 1M such sends in  total.

Comment: @DarthVader traffic is not leaving the network.

Answer (score 2):

[Heisenberg uncertainty principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) in a broad sense. More specifically, if you have two programs on a computer where one is sending data and the other is analyzing it - then you're taxing the CPU with two tasks, where as if your monitoring program is running on a different computer - your sender has the benefit of not having to compete with anyone else and will always be faster.

Don't test network throughput with both programs on the same machine.

Comment: and it's not even network throughput.. actually I am not sure why he measured this.

Comment: This was not what I intended to measure but just a observation with no explanation I could think of. I am running this on 8 CPU box with CPU isolation and pinning so that both processes dont step on each other.